# Bundles and frameworks "lost" after Xcode restart

Tags: xcode

I'm working with a framework in my XCode project where I first add a bundle via "Copy Bundle Resources" and then I link in the framework via "Link Binary with Libraries." Both files exist *outside* my project folder. I do NOT use the "Copy items into destination group's folder" option.

I can work on my app and it runs great. I kill Xxode, restart it, and even though I see the bundle and framework listed, the project won't compile anymore. I have to remove both and re-add them to get it to work.

Comment: Is the framework available as a cocoapod? That way, re-building is easier. Xcode 5 is full of errors (my experience) so anything could be going on. Also I guess you mean closing Xcode, not forcing it to close.

Comment: Nope, this is an internal project only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the framework in your copy bundle resources phase. You should only need it in link binary w/libraries and in your build settings framework search path

Comment: Hmm - what is (sorry where is) the build settings framework search path?

Comment: In the project navigator click on the project itself. You should have a few tabs in the main project window. On general you should be able to scroll down and see your framework in linked frameworks and libraries. Build settings tab is long and takes a while to figure out... the fastest way to get to the setting is the search box in the upper right. Type "framework search" and it should be the only thing there. The search box works pretty good. It searches pretty names, the underlaying xml key and the values so its great for hunting things down.

Comment: One more thing that helps when strange stuff is going on... dump your derived data folder. It's easiest to just open it from the command line and kill all the folders in it... `open ~ray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: Oh wow. Get this. I'm storing my framework in a folder that has a space. In the list I see:

Comment: Shoot, damn enter to submit. Anyway, I see 2 lines for the path. XCode split it in two.

Comment: yeah i haven't had a lot of luck with dragging things into Xcode and it setting everything right. The other thing you have to watch out for is it putting a hard path to your user folder. (doesn't work so well if someone else opens your project) It should be using one of the special variables like so: `"$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/Omniture"`